# Jsoup, java, android studio - no results

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I am currently writing an android app in android studio. I would like to connect with gog.com and search for a specific game. I have done this with steam and it works fine. When I want to search for a game at *https://www.gog.com/games?page=1&search=game_title&sort=popularity* it does not work.

Piece of my code:

```
String search ="https://www.gog.com/games?page=1&search=cyberpunk&sort=popularity";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(search).get();
Elements titles = doc.getElementsByClass("product-tile__title");
for(Element title: titles){
    txt = title.text();
    Log.i("My_title", txt);
}
```

I wrote "cyberpunk" by default. This link works in a browser, but when I use Jsoup the same link returns "No results found". Is it a problem with cookie/user-agent/language ?

Comment: You have 99 titles but all of them are empty like this => <div ng-bind="tile.data.title" class="product-tile__title"></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're right, your code should be working but in this particular case it will not work.

The reason is because if you disable javascript on your browser, and make this GET request `https://www.gog.com/games?page=1&search=cyberpunk&sort=popularity` you will see that the page will not load, and the reason is because these html elements are constructed or loaded by a javascript code.

So in this case you will have to parse the json that you received in your response instead of using `JSOUP`.

#### Conclusion

Because JSOUP can't run javascript as it's not a webbrowser, you will not be able to parse the HTML response in this case, but instead, parse the JSON in the HTML response.